# Rstudio and ggplot, stacked bar graph: Two almost identical bits of code, fct_reorder works with one, and not the other?

Tags: ggplot2, geom-bar

**I wrote this which perfectly reorders the variable `mcr_variant` by count on my bar graph.**

```
mcrxgenus %>%
  mutate(mcr_variant = fct_reorder(mcr_variant, count)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(fill=isolate_genus, y=count, x=mcr_variant)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x="MCR variant", y="Count", fill="Isolate genus")
```

**I wrote this to display the same dataset a bit differently.**

```
mcrxgenus %>%
  mutate(isolate_genus = fct_reorder(isolate_genus, count)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(fill=mcr_variant, y=count, x=isolate_genus)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity")+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(x="Isolate genus", y="Count", fill="MCR variant")
```

**It does NOT reorder my bar graph by count. I have absolutely no idea what is going on. It seems to me there should be no reason for this. mcr_variant and isolate_genus are both categorical variables. mcr_variant has 12 levels and isolate_genus has 6 possible levels. That is the only difference I can think of. Anyone run in to this problem before? It's been driving me mad! I have no idea what is happening here!**

Answer (score 2):

When you stack bars up, you're adding their values. `fct_reorder`, by default, takes the median of the values. So if MCR Variant `A` has counts 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, its order will be determined by the median count, 1, while its height is the sum of the counts, 6. Meanwhile if MCR Variant `B` has counts 2, 3, its order will be the median 2.5, but its sum is 5.

You need to make `fct_reorder` use `sum`, just like your stacked bar graph. Replace `fct_reorder(isolate_genus, count)` with `fct_reorder(isolate_genus, count, sum)`.

If this doesn't work, please share a reproducible sample of data, preferably with `dput` so the classes are preserved and everything is copy/pasteable e.g., `dput(mcrxgenus[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows. Pick a suitable sample to illustrate the problem.